# Php Web Scraping saving Tik Tok video from url

Tags: php, html, video

I am trying to save videos from this url:

Original: `https://api.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/playwm/?video_id=v09044340000bq0vmd39if221ld9o5n0`

Link changes to this: `http://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/e50056249a925719f71ce8618053e173/5eee4e39/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/47799d9a28024de4a9ac1c7f3e452821/?a=1180&br=3482&bt=1741&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=6&er=&l=202006201157550101151192330B0ADC98&lr=tiktok&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=Mzg8bzVpPGd5dDMzNzczM0ApaDo3Zjw6N2U3NzY5ZTs3NmdrbGEuL2Ywai1fLS0wMTZzczYvMC4zNDY0YS9jNl41Mi06Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=`

The video is from TikTok. When you go to the url, it instantly redirects you to another url. The other url is the one I want in order to save the video. However, the url it directs you to does not have a "view html source" option. I can inspect the element and that shows it has a video tag, but I cannot find a way to save the url between the tag. I am using php and html. I tried to do this with Download, but to no effect

```
<?php
$VidUrl = "http://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/e50056249a925719f71ce8618053e173/5eee4e39/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/47799d9a28024de4a9ac1c7f3e452821/?a=1180&br=3482&bt=1741&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=6&er=&l=202006201157550101151192330B0ADC98&lr=tiktok&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=Mzg8bzVpPGd5dDMzNzczM0ApaDo3Zjw6N2U3NzY5ZTs3NmdrbGEuL2Ywai1fLS0wMTZzczYvMC4zNDY0YS9jNl41Mi06Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=";

?>

<a href="<?php echo $VidUrl; ?>" class="btn btn-block btn-warning mt-3" download="tiktom.mp4">
    Download
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

First create a download.php file and put this:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($name) . "\""); 
readfile($url); 

?>
```

link your download url like this to the download file:

```
   <a href="download.php?url=https://api.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/playwm/?video_id=v09044340000bq0vmd39if221ld9o5n0&name=SomeName.mp4">Download</a>
```